# Wordpress template next_prev

Tags: posts, next

I have next and prev with a gallery and the select is not ok and I have no idea how to change. I want to make the select by two category not by a status (publish)

```
function in_conference_prev_next_posts() {
    $cmsmasters_post_type = get_post_type();

    $published_posts = wp_count_posts($cmsmasters_post_type)->publish;


    if ($published_posts > 1) {
        echo '<aside class="post_nav">';

        previous_post_link('<span class="cmsmasters_prev_post">%link<span class="cmsmasters_prev_arrow"><span></span></span><span class="sub">previous</span></span>');

        next_post_link('<span class="cmsmasters_next_post">%link<span class="cmsmasters_next_arrow"><span></span></span><span class="sub">next</span></span>');

        echo '</aside>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/previous_post_link

I'm a little confused by what you are asking but I'm assuming you are after the next/prev links to go to the next or previous post in the same category? In which case, you need to define the third argument in 'previous_post_link' & 'next_post_link' as 'true'.

Note that those two functions must be used inside "the loop" to work.

Comment: Now the request is working for all the cateogries..but I want to make for just two category not for all

Comment: Then you'll need to exclude using the fourth parameter.

Comment: But I want two exactly category from all..how can I do this? on my code

Comment: You could query the posts based on the two categories and it would get the next/prev items from those two categories using:

`'category' => array(1,2)`

With get_posts();

Comment: Can you help me..Not working for me..I don't know how to implement in my code

Comment: I'd need to see more of your code, like where this function is being used to help. Paste your template file on pastebin.com and post the link here and i'll happily take a look for you.

Comment: Here is the layout code

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Px0Ri7Jm